# Netlogo Patch can't access a turtle variable without specifying which turtle

Tags: netlogo

Im trying to setup a procedure to change the colour of the outer patches of my cell-like patches so that it can be easily identified which cell is which. So far I have the below code but im getting issues when trying to go-once the program. Code is below

```
globals [
  radius 
]
patches-own [
  patch-state
  CellID
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set radius 2
  create-turtles #cells [
    ifelse mode =  "Restricted"
    [ setxy random-float #units - random-float #units random-float #units - random-float #units ]
    [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
   ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  expand-cells
  make-membrane
  tick
end

to expand-cells
  set radius radius + 1
  ask turtles [ ask patches in-radius radius [
    if pcolor = black or CellID = [who] of myself + 1 [
      build-up-cells 
    ]
   ]
  ]
  ask patches with [ pcolor = black ] [
   set patch-state "X"
  ]
end

to build-up-cells
  set pcolor [ color ] of myself
  set CellID [who] of myself + 1
end

to make-membrane
  ask patches with [pcolor != black] [
    ifelse not any? neighbors with [ CellID = [who] of myself + 1 ]
    [ set patch-state "I" ]
    [ set patch-state "M" ]
  ]
  ask patches with [ patch-state = "M" ] [
    set pcolor pcolor - 1
  ]
  trim
end

to trim
end
```

Error im getting is this:
A patch can't access a turtle variable without specifying which turtle.
error while patch 40 6 running OF
called by procedure MAKE-MEMBRANE
called by procedure GO
called by Button 'go-once'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to troubleshoot this out of the box, since your code refers to items on your Interface tab. You may have better luck with a response if you build a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by stripping back your code to *just* what is needed to recreate your issue so that users can copy-paste your code and run it immediately.

Comment: Note that almost anytime you're tempted to use `who` in NetLogo, there's a better solution. It's really rare for good NetLogo code to ever use `who` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error results from the wrong usage of `who`. If you take a look into the [Netlogo dictionary](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/), you will see that `who` is a turtle variable, but you run `make-membrane` on the patches.

I guess, what you want to do is check, if there are any neighbors, that don't belong to the same cells (i.e. don't have the same `CellID`), and if so, make that patch a membrane patch.

```
ifelse any? neighbors with [ CellID != [CellID] of myself]
    [ set patch-state "M" ]
    [ set patch-state "I" ]
```